# Windows 7 ignores F6/F8 and will not boot

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have a work PC with sophos safeguard encryption on it.

When I bootup I receive an error saying a recent hardware or software change might be the cause:

> Windows failed to start.
>   File:  \Boot\BCD 
>   Status:  0xc0000098 
>   Info:  The windows boot configuration data file does not contain a valid OS entry.

This began after the PC forced me to run a system recovery.  My machine had powered down improperly (power outage?) and simply would not respond to my keyboard input to cancel the option to scan my system.  After the scan "repaired" a boot file, my system crashed.  Now it tells me I can insert my windows 7 disk and run recovery.

I can't simply do this because of Safeguard.  The system recovery can't see my encrypted drive.  I tried hitting F2 to manually login to Safeguard and then selected the option to boot from media.  The computer prompts me to hit any key to boot from disk...which I do, but once again it is not reading my keyboard input.

I can't get <kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> to bypass startup files and get me to a command prompt like the old days.  If I could get to a command prompt I might could recover the file windows jacked up from its backup location...though I may need to use the windows recovery disk UI to do this..???

In the past I've been able to slap in a PS/2 keyboard when the USB keyboards stop responding like this.  I have no PS/2 keyboard available.

Anyone have any idea how I can undo the damage windows system recovery has done with safeguard installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "though I may need to use the windows recovery disk UI to do this..???"

You can make a system repair disk on any Windows 7 PC, just be sure it is the same bit version 32 or 64.

Go to the start menu > All Programs >  Maintenance folder > create a system repair disc

I would find/buy a ps2 keyboard, might be easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Boot config is messed up, like the information says:

> data file does not contain a valid OS entry.
>   So if windows is not starting you cant get into any recovery mode.

Start windows from cd, go to console, ant launch bootrec, or bcdedit

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/pl

Comment: -1 Did you read the question?

Comment: To the +1...In my question I state "I can't simply do this because of Safeguard. The system recovery can't see my encrypted drive" By this I mean I cannot simply insert the disk and run system recovery. I also expounded on how this has already been attempted along with the results. Please explain to me how this RTFM answer is helpful given this information.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in BIOS to ensure USB-keyboard is supported or something like that, otherwise I think the best option is to get an USB-PS/2 adapter.